# Angular velocity in difference reference frames

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, rotational-kinematics

For finding angular velocity of one frame w.r.t another, after going through some websites, I saw there are two forms to represent it as follows.

1. $$ \vec\omega_{ba}= \vec\omega_b−\vec\omega_a$$
2. $$ ω_{ba} = \frac{\text{relative velocity of B wrt A perpendicular to AB}}{\text{Separation between A and B}}=\frac{(\vec v_{ba})}{r_{ba}}=\frac{|\vec v_b−\vec v_a|}{|\vec r_b-\vec r_a|} $$

However, the textbook that I was reading mentioned that the first one is incorrect without stating the reason. Why is the first expression wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Terms in #1 represent angular velocity, but each in a different frame of reference.  One needs an expression where all of the symbols represent quantities in the same frame.

Comment: @garyp No, both $ \vec\omega_b$ and $\vec\omega_a$ represent angular velocity in ground frame of reference. The subscript is just for the which particle is being referred to in ground frame. Also, $ \vec\omega_{ba} $ represents angular velocity of _b_ in reference frame of _a_

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: None of your equations are rigorous enough.

Angular velocity is always angular velocity from a particle (or a system of particles) *with respect to some reference*. I assume you are in inertial non-relativistic frames. Let $S$ and $S'$ be two frames, where $\vec{v}$ is the constant velocity of $S'$ respect from $S$. Let $\vec{r}$, $\vec{r '}$, $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{u'}$ be the positions and velocities of a body in $S$ and $S'$ respectively. We know that:

$$\vec{r} = \vec{r'} + \vec{v} t $$
$$\vec{u} = \vec{u'} + \vec{v} $$

By definition, $\vec{u} = \vec{\Delta r} \times \vec{\omega}$, where $\vec{\Delta r} = \vec{r} - \vec{r_0}$ is the vector from the reference point to the particle and $\vec{\omega}$ is the angular velocity, which is perpendicular to the plane of rotation.

Given a particle that only rotates in the XY plane of $S'$, along a circle centered in $\vec{r_0 '}$, we have two choices:

If we want to interpret that there are two different *pure planar rotational systems* both in $S$ and $S'$, then $\vec{u} = \vec{\Delta r} \times \vec{\omega}$ and $\vec{u'} = \vec{\Delta r '} \times \vec{\omega '}$. Now, since we are assuming that the reference is *fixed*, let the origin of $S$ and $S'$ be synchronized in $t=0$. Then $\vec{r_0} = \vec{r_0 '}$ and $\vec{\Delta r} = \vec{\Delta r'} + \vec{v} t$. Then:

$$\vec{u} = \vec{u'} + \vec{v} = \vec{\Delta r '} \times \vec{\omega '} + \vec{v} $$
$$\vec{u} = \vec{\Delta r} \times \vec{\omega} = \vec{\Delta r '} \times \vec{\omega} + (\vec{v} t) \times \vec{\omega} = \vec{\Delta r '} \times \vec{\omega} + t (\vec{v} \times \vec{\omega})$$
$$ \vec{\Delta r '} \times \vec{\omega '} + \vec{v} = \vec{\Delta r '} \times \vec{\omega} + t (\vec{v} \times \vec{\omega})$$

I don't think it's possible to simplify any more. To find $\vec{\omega}$ in terms of $\vec{\omega '}$ you should compute the cross product and solve the equality component by component. Just think in a particular case in order to make sense of the result. If $\vec{v} = v \breve{i}$, then as $t$ goes to infinity both y and z components of $\vec{\omega}$ vanishes (in $S$). This makes sense because, in $S$, $\vec{\Delta r}$ increases every time more, but since the magnitude of $\vec{u}$ remains constant, then the non parallel components of $\vec{\omega}$ must be every time less. Of course, in $S'$, $\vec{\Delta r'}$ remains bounded in all its components so $\vec{\omega '}$ doesn't vanish. Actually, with a movement in XY plane, in $S'$ will be $\vec{\omega '} = \omega_z ' \breve{k}$, $\vec{\Delta r '}$ normal and $\vec{u '}$ tangential to the body.

As you might see, this analysis is a bit tedious so there's the second possibility. If we want to interpret that in $S'$ there's a *pure planar rotational system* and in $S$ theres a *roto-traslational system*, then:

$$\vec{u} = \vec{u'} + \vec{v} = \vec{\Delta r '} \times \vec{\omega '} + \vec{v} = \vec{\Delta r } \times \vec{\omega} + \vec{v} $$

In this case, in $S$ the reference is not fixed, but moves along with the reference of $S'$. That is, $\vec{r_0} = \vec{r_0'} + \vec{v} t$ so $\vec{\Delta r} = \vec{\Delta r '}$. Therefore, the velocity of $S$ consists in two contributions: one comes from the rotation movement, and other from the traslation movement. With this second interpretation it holds that $\vec{\omega} = \vec{\omega '}$.

Comment: I'm in 11th grade, so most of what you say is at a rather advanced level. For my level, we don't go that rigorously into vectors in 3D, mostly, all of it in is in 2D, that's why you might see a lack of rigorousness. I would appreciate if you could also answer my question for 2D, with a little simplicity. For reference, I have edited my question and added a picture of the textbook that I was talking about.